# Highcharts percentage variability position

Tags: javascript, highcharts

While percentage of each piece of pie chart reach 50%( or 52% and 48%) the position of percentage is changed, namely is not the same when was 16% and 84% each piece of graph.
The code that I use is:

[image]

```
Highcharts.chart('container1', {
    chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false,
        type: 'pie',
        options3d: {
            enabled: true,
          alpha:70,
            beta: 0
        }
    },
    title: {
        text: ''
    },

    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            allowPointSelect: false,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            size:100,
            depth: 15,


               dataLabels: {
               textOverflow:'none',
                      enabled: true,
                    color:'black',
                    connectorColor:'transparent',
                    format:'{point.percentage:.1f}%',
                    distance:-30,
                    style:{
                    textShadow:false}
                },
                showInLegend: false
        }
    },
 series: [{
        type: 'pie',
        name: 'ΑΞΚΟΙ - ΑΝΘΣΤΕΣ',

        data: [   
            ['Παρόντες',   <?php
               while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res2)) {
                   while( $row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res1)){
                    $row3['COUNT(*)']=$row2['COUNT(*)'] - $row1['COUNT(*)'];
                    echo $row3['COUNT(*)'];

                    }
                }?>],
            ['Απόντες', <?php


                      while( $row3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res3)){

                    echo $row3['COUNT(*)'];

                    }

                    ?>]
]  
    }]
});
```

There is a feature that can I use in order to make position of percentage constant?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Any advice from someone who knows about highcharts?

Comment: Hard to understand what you want

Comment: @teo please attach some images showing what you are looking for?

Comment: @ewolden check the edited post. As you can see when each piece of pie chart reach 50%( or 52% and 48%) the position of percentage is changed

Comment: Okay, so you want the label to stay in a fixed position. Will you always have 2 different series, or will the number of different series vary?

Comment: I want percentages to stay in fixed pisition an also I have only 2 different series

Comment: Can't find a way, here is a working fiddle with the above pie: https://jsfiddle.net/k6nvzhy6/

Answer (score 0):

You can set fixed position of the data labels by calling `Highcharts.SVGElement.attr()` function on each label:

```
events: {
  load: function() {
    var points = this.series[0].points;
    points.forEach((p) => p.connector.destroy()); // destroy connectors

    // set fixed position for both points
    points[0].dataLabel.attr({
      x: 300,
      y: 100
    });
    points[1].dataLabel.attr({
      x: 75,
      y: 100
    });
  }
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/8z3g1LLy/

**API reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#attr